# passing javascript array to php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to post a javascript array to my php function on the same page as follows each box is clicked adding a new number to the array and then you click deletephotos and it edits the database to del = 2; but it says the array is undefined but i have used "alert" to show the array does have values in

Javascript

```
var numberlist = new Array();
function selectImage(div){

    var whichDiv = "selectdiv" + div ;
    var opa = document.getElementById(whichDiv).style.opacity;
    if(opa == '0'){
     document.getElementById(whichDiv).style.opacity = '1';
     document.getElementById(whichDiv).style.display = 'block';
     numberlist.push(div);
     alert(numberlist);
    }else{
    document.getElementById(whichDiv).style.opacity = '0';
     document.getElementById(whichDiv).style.display = 'none';
     var index = numberlist.indexOf(div);
     if (index > -1) {
    numberlist.splice(index, 1);

    alert(numberlist);
}
}
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['deletephotos'])){
$javascriptarray = $_POST['numberlist'];
$javascriptarray = explode(',', $javascriptarray);  

foreach($javascriptarray as $val) {

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE gallery SET del='2' WHERE id='$val'")
    or die(mysql_error());


}
}

?>
```

Comment: Simply take checkbox names as `name="photo_data[]"`. This will pass all selected checkbox values as array.

Comment: Are you using ajax? is there a form somewhere? Are we missing some code?

Comment: Im not using any forms no just when i click a div it has an onclick function t add the selected div id onto an array and when you click submit at the end it runs the php function, the only for is for the submit button to be posted.

Comment: You have to use `form` or `Ajax` to send your JS array to php.

Comment: right but that is the part i do not understand how to do i need some explanation on this as i have looked everywhere... all i need is to be able to use the array i created in the javascript when i have clicked delete photos i need the javascript array in my php script so it can loop through it

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have forms in your page there is no need to create an array with javascript.

Create a dummy(hidden) form that has the same number of fields as divs.

Then use javascript to assign values to the form elements after which you now submit the form with javascript.

```
    <div style="visibility:hidden">
     <form name="dummy" action="process_pic.php" method="post">
  //process_pic.php is the php file that the form values will be passed to.
```

The name attribute holds all the trick, values assigned to the input elements are automatically added to the "pic[]" array.

```
    <script>
    var item1 = document.getElementById(pic1);
    var item2 = document.getElementById(pic2);
    var item3 = document.getElementById(pic3);
//If there are no other form elements on the page, you can get elements in an array using:   var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
//Assign values (you can do this in a loop if you have the elements in an array)
    item1 = 3
    item2 = 5
    item3 = 1

    //Submit form
    document.dummy.submit();
    </script>
```

Inside the process_pic.php you can now work with the array as you please

```
$php_array =  array();
$php_array =  $_POST[pic];
```

You can now work with the array as you please.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a json string representation of your array and pass it to php using ajax

Comment: so use var JSONnumberlist = JSON.stringify(numberlist); instead of var numberlist = new Array(); ?

Comment: yes , and to pass it to php you have to use ajax or your form

Comment: what would the ajax be, sorry im completly stuck on this one and dont really understand it.. i have the JSON.stringify(numberlist); but what would the code be so i can use it in my php function instead of the $javascriptarray = $_POST['numberlist'];